# Is it possible to launch more than one Webstorm instance using the command-line launcher?

Tags: ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Webstorm can be launched from the command line using the command `wstorm`. However, would it be possible to launch more than one instance? Usually, the second time I run `wstorm`, it doesn't open another Webstorm for me and does nothing.

Comment: But .. it never launches second instance anyway. Even when you open 2 projects at the same time (2 frames) -- only one instance is used.

Comment: Okay, so is it possible to open more than one project at a time?

Comment: Yes -- when you opening another project (e.g. "File | Reopen") it should ask you how you would like to open it. If it does not ask -- please check your settings: `Settings | General | Project Opening`

Comment: I'm specifically asking if it can be done from the command line launcher, i.e. `wstorm`, not the GUI.

Comment: You should be able -- just pass path to the project (where .idea subfolder is) as a parameter -- it should behave in the same way (should open new/reuse existing/ask for frame according to the settings).

Comment: Doesn't for me... just dies silently.

Comment: Not sure then -- works fine here on Windows 7: 1) Using full path to the IDE executable (since it's not in the PATH); 2) passing full path to the project; 3) opens in new frame automatically. It's PhpStorm .. but it's almost the same as WebStorm. Example command: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PhpStorm\bin\PhpStorm" E:\Projects\web\_idetest`. Possibly launcher works a bit differently (but it should not -- it should accept such _basic_ parameters as path to the project)

Comment: @PaolodelMundo On a mac and using now WebStorm 11, `wstorm` does not open a new instance

Comment: @MikeFielden, Try **Tools > Create Command-line Launcher** (see answer below).

Answer (score 8):

In OS X, this is apparently caused by an outdated `wstorm` (a Python script at `/usr/local/bin/wstorm`). I verified the solution indicated in this [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21446) with WebStorm 2016.1.3:

- Go to **Tools > Create Command-line Launcher...**.

  [image]

**UPDATE Nov-2016:** As of WebStorm 2016.3, the default name of the launcher changed from `wstorm` to `webstorm`. If you prefer `wstorm` instead, make sure to edit the script name before clicking OK:

[image]

Comment: Works with OS X El Capitan and WebStorm 2016.2

Comment: Thank you for this fix. With the 2018.2.5 update, this feature stopped working. I followed your instructions and changed the launcher from webstorm to wstorm and now it launches multiple projects as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```
WebStorm.exe "Full\path\to\the\project\that\contains\the\.idea\folder\of\your\project"
```

The project will run in the same instance but in a separted window as described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/opening-multiple-projects.html

**NOTE:** This was tested on WebStorm 9.0.3 and may not work on previous versions.

Comment: This doesn't help for WebStorm 2016.1.3 on OS X El Capitan.